# Make my rectangle randomly fall down from my screen?

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to make a game and am almost done with the code. But I can't make my rectangle randomly fall down from my screen.

I am coding a car game that is supposed to dodge the other cars. But is not working. can someone help me?

```java
int carx = 200;
int cary = 0;
float speedx = 0;
float speedy = 0;
float accy = 0.1;

color rod = color(255, 0, 0);
color vit = color(255);

final int START_STATE = 1;
final int PLAY_STATE = 2;
final int GAMEOVER_STATE = 3;
final int RESTART = 4;

int state = START_STATE;

void setup() {
  size(400, 700);
}

void draw() {
  switch (state) {
    case START_STATE:
      drawStart();
      break;
    case PLAY_STATE:
      drawPlay();
      break;
    case GAMEOVER_STATE:
      drawGameOver();
    case RESTART:
      drawrestart();
  }
}

void init() {
  carx = 200;
  cary = 0;
  speedx = 0;
  speedy = 0;
  accy = 0.1;
}

void drawStart() {
  background(0);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  textSize(16);
  text("Click the mouse button to start the game", width / 2, height / 2);
  if (mousePressed) {
    state = PLAY_STATE;
  }
}

void drawGameOver() {
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  textSize(20);
  text("you have crashed your car", width / 2, height / 2);
  if (mousePressed) {
    state = PLAY_STATE;
    init();
  }
}

void drawrestart() {
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  textSize(15);
  text("press mouse to restart", 200, 400);
  if (keyPressed) {
    state = RESTART;
  }
}

void drawPlay() {
  background(0);

  if (get(carx, cary) == vit) {
    speedy = -1 * speedy;
  }
  fill(rod);

  rect(carx, cary, 50, 30);

  if (get(mouseX, 600) == color(255, 0, 0)) {
    state = GAMEOVER_STATE;
  }
  fill(#FFFFFF);
  rect(mouseX, 600, 30, 50);

  carx += speedx;
  cary += speedy;
  speedy += accy;
}
```

Comment: it looks like you're not sure what language that is. Neither am I.

Comment: JAVA is NOT JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have at the moment only has one rectangle fall down from the top for each 'round' of the game. I'm not sure if you wanted to have multiple blocks falling; I think that would be a good next step.

For now, here's a simple hack which will cause the block to fall from a random position each time, like you requested.

At the very start of your code, outside of the functions, place:

```
boolean randomise;
```

Then, within void init() you should add:

```
randomise = true;
```

Finally, add this section into drawPlay(), right at the start of the function:

```
if (randomise){
  carx = int(random(width-50));
  randomise = false;
}
```

Note that a new random x co-ordinate will only generate every time you set the boolean 'randomise' to true again. So if you generate a new iteration with more than one block falling inside the drawPlay() function, you should bear this in mind and adjust the code accordingly.

------- [EDIT] -------

Hi, glad that this helped.

I've actually noticed another little issue which I will help you fix.

Currently, you are checking at mouseX to see whether there has been a collision. This works (mostly), but if the right side of the player's white car drives through the left edge of a red falling block, then the game continues as though nothing has happened. What should occur is that the game is over because a collision is detected. You want to find out if any part of the two shapes have overlapped.

To do this, you should alter the code like so. In drawPlay(), replace:

```
if (get(mouseX, 600) == color(255, 0, 0)) {
    state = GAMEOVER_STATE;
  }
```

with:

```
  if (get(mouseX, 600) == color(255, 0, 0) || get(mouseX + 30, 600) == color(255, 0, 0)) {
    state = GAMEOVER_STATE;
  }
```

This is an OR statement - checking whether either side of the player's car has collided. This way, every time they bump into each other, the game will end.

Now for your question: how to add multiple cars?

There are a few ways you could go about this, but I'll show you the most straightforward.

In drawPlay(), you want to add this little if statement:

```
  if (cary > height){
    init();
  }
```

Basically what we're doing here is checking if the previous red block/car has fallen off the bottom of the sketch. If it has, i.e. if the red block's y co-ordinate is larger than the height of the whole sketch, we call init() again. This will reset everything, including making randomise true. Once randomise is true, the previous code you added will select a random start point for the block, and it will fall all over again.

I hope you've understood everything I explained - whilst my code will fix your problem, the best way to learn is to try to solve things by yourself. Check out [Dan Shiffman's videos on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/user/shiffman/playlists?view=50&sort=dd&shelf_id=2). These are a great starting place to get to grips with Processing - hopefully you'll be more confident writing your own code after following along with his examples :)

Comment: How do i make multiple rectangle to fall down together? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well thanks again. But now when i writen the code in processing there is int multiple blocks that are falling down. Do you want to take a look at the code,Please?

Comment: Hi Mustafa. I tested the code with all these additions and it works for me. Note the 'multiple block' code I suggested only has one block at a time fall down. There is continually going to be only one block falling, but once the previous one is gone, a new one replaces it. A very easy solution would be to copy and paste the block code multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`random`](https://processing.org/reference/random_.html) to generate a random x coordinate:

```java
carx = (int)random(0, width-50);
```

Reset the position and the speed of the care, once the car reached to bottom of the window:

```java
void drawPlay() {

    if (cary > height) {
        carx = (int)random(0, width-50);
        cary = 0;
        speedy = 0;
    }

    // [...]
```